# cakephp 3 image upload

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to upload image by cakephp 3. I have tried the code below which was working in cakephp 2. Now in cakephp 3 I have tried the code below

database field

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `avatar` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ;
```

Then in users add.ctp I have created below form

```
<?= $this->Form->create($user,['type' => 'file']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('avatar',['type' => 'file']);?> 
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

In user model I have added this validation

```
$validator
            ->add('avatar', [

                'uploadError' => [
                        'rule' => 'uploadError',
                        'message' => 'The cover image upload failed.',
                        'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
                ],

                'mimeType' => [
                        'rule' => array('mimeType', array('image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg')),
                        'message' => 'Please only upload images (gif, png, jpg).',
                        'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
                ],

                'fileSize' => [
                        'rule' => array('fileSize', '<=', '1MB'),
                        'message' => 'Cover image must be less than 1MB.',
                        'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
                ],

                'processCoverUpload' => [
                        'rule' => 'processCoverUpload',
                        'message' => 'Unable to process cover image upload.',
                        'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
                ],

            ]);
```

After that I found this error

```
ext/fileinfo is required for validating file mime types
```

After [ndm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392379/ndm)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708673/cakephp-3-image-upload#comment51357456_31708673), I have changed

```
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

in the php.ini file

Then this error has been gone. But the new error that I found

```
error : Method processCoverUpload does not exist
```

But in the method below I have added

```
 public function processCoverUpload($check = array()) {
            if (!is_uploaded_file($check['avatar']['tmp_name'])) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            if (!move_uploaded_file($check['avatar']['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'uploads' . DS . $check['avatar']['name'])) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            $this->data[$this->alias]['avatar'] = 'uploads/'. $check['avatar']['name'];
            return TRUE;
    }
```

I don't know why Method processCoverUpload does not exist. Can you explain?

Comment: Well, the error message is pretty clear, isn't it? CakePHP 3.x now requires the fileinfo extension. **http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php**

Comment: Thanks ndm you are always awesome. If you don't mind may you see my question again ? I have just edit it, because I have found another error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, CakePHP 3.x now requires the fileinfo extension for validating mime types.

**http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php**

The other error happens because you haven't defined a provider where your custom method can be found. You've most likely added the method to your table class, so in that case you should use the `table` provider

```
'processCoverUpload' => [
        'provider' => 'table', // <<<< there you go
        'rule' => 'processCoverUpload',
        'message' => 'Unable to process cover image upload.',
        'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
],
```

The default provider is defined to use the `\Cake\Validation\Validation` class.

On a side note, `$check` wont contain the field name as a key, validation methods will receive the plain value that the key in the data holds.

Also `$this->data` doesn't exist anymore, things are working different now in 3.x. If you want to modify the data, then you should use the [**`beforeMarshal`**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforemarshal) or [**`beforeSave`**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforesave) events. However, with the latter you'll run into problems in case the upload field is using the same name as the column in the database which stores the file path, as this will cause the array to be marshalled to the type of the column, which is most probably a string type: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/5998**

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Validation > Validation Providers](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#validation-providers)**
- **[Cookbook > Validation > Adding Validation Providers](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#adding-validation-providers)**
- **[Cookbook > ... ORM > Saving Data > Modifying Request Data Before Building Entities](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#before-marshal)**

Comment: @AlimonKarim `debug($check);` And before you ask about the next problem, `$this->data` doesn't exist anymore, things are different now in 3.x, if you want to modify the data, then you should use the [**`beforeMarshal`**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforemarshal) or [**`beforeSave`**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforesave) events. Also **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/5998**